# Properties of V and I in algebraic geometry.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $\lambda \in \Lambda$ (an arbitrary set of indices). Let $S_\lambda \subseteq \mathbb C [X_1, \dots, X_n]$ and $T_\lambda \subseteq A^n (\mathbb C )$ (the complex affine space).

I have to prove (if true) or find a counterexample (if false) for the two following statements:

1. $\bigcup _{\lambda \in \Lambda} \mathrm V (S_\lambda) \subseteq \mathrm V \left( \bigcap _{\lambda \in \Lambda } S_\lambda \right)$ and there exists $S\subseteq \mathbb C [X_1, \dots, X_n]$ such that $\bigcup _{\lambda \in \Lambda} \mathrm V (S_\lambda) = \mathrm V (S)$.
2. $\bigcap _{\lambda \in \Lambda} \mathrm I (T_\lambda) \supseteq \mathrm I \left( \bigcup _{\lambda \in \Lambda } T_\lambda \right)$ and there exists $T\subseteq A^n (\mathbb C)$ such that $\bigcap _{\lambda \in \Lambda} \mathrm I (T_\lambda) = \mathrm I (T)$.

I need some hints to approach this exercise, because I don't know where to begin. I tried to apply Nullstelensatz in both cases to see if I get some property that I already know, but it didn't work. Also, I tried some examples in case 1 and I think it is true (so I would have to prove it). But it is more difficult to think of examples in case 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take $\bar{x} \in  \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} V(S_\lambda)$. Then for some $\lambda'$ we  will have that
   $ \bar{x} \in V(S_{\lambda'})$, so 
   $$\forall f \in S_{\lambda'} \quad f(\bar{x}) = 0$$
   But $\bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} S_\lambda \subseteq S_{\lambda'}$, so all the polinomial in this set are zero on $\bar{x}$. (which proves the first half point)

The second half is false and the counterexample is in $\mathbb{C}[X]$. For each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ consider $S_q = \{ x - q \}$. It is trivial to show that
$$ \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} V(S_q) = \mathbb{Q} $$
but $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be a variety.

2. The second point is very similar to the first one. Take $f \in I \left( \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} T_\lambda \right)$. So for all $\lambda' \in \Lambda$, we have that

$$ f(\bar{x}) = 0 \quad \forall \bar{x} \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} T_\lambda \quad \Rightarrow \quad f(\bar{x}) = 0 \quad \forall \bar{x} \in T_{\lambda'}$$
So for all $\lambda' \in \Lambda$ we have $f \in I(T_{\lambda'}) \Rightarrow f \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} I(T_\lambda)$.

This time the second half is true, because if you take $f \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} I(T_\lambda)$, then for all $\lambda \in \Lambda$ we have that
$$f (\bar{x}) = 0 \quad \forall \bar{x} \in  T_\lambda \quad \Rightarrow \quad f (\bar{x}) = 0 \quad \forall \bar{x} \in \bigcup{\lambda \in \Lambda} T_\lambda$$
And so we actually have that
$$ f \in I \left( \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} T_\lambda \right) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} I(T_\lambda) = \left( \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} T_\lambda \right) $$

Comment: Why $\mathbb Q$ cannot be a variety?

Comment: you are working with polinolinomial in one variable, so all the variety can be written as $V(f)$ - this can be prooved using MCD.

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinitely many points a polinomial $f$ with finite degree cannot be zero in all those points, without beeing the zero polinomial

Comment: I understand what you mean with duality, but when I try to prove the second statement explicitly I get stuck when I apply $I$ to both sides (it reverses the containment, but I don't know how to continue).

Comment: I have proven that the second point is false. Let $T_1= V(X)$ and $T_2 = V(X+1)$. Then $I(T_1 \cup T_2) \nsubseteq I(T_1 ) \cap I(T_2) = \langle 0 \rangle$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you are in $\mathbb{C}[X]$, so $V(X) = \{ 0 \}, \: V(X+1) = \{ -1 \}$. Then $T_1 \cup T_2 = \{-1,0\}$. So, all the polinomial in $I(T_1 \cup T_2)$ are zero over $0$ and $-1$, thus $x(x+1)$ divides them all. It follows that $I(T_1 \cup T_2) = (x^2 + x)$ where on the left i mean the idel generated by that polinomial...

Instead, $I(T_1) $ is the set of all polinomial which is zero over $0$, so $x$ divides them all. idem for $I(T_2) = (x+1)$. Then we have that $I(T_1) \cap I(T_2) = (x) \cap (x+1) = (x^2 + x) = I(T_1 \cup T_2)$

Comment: anyway it wasn't as trivial as i thought so I've edited the proof